# AWK code parser, distinguish division from regex

Tags: regex, parsing, awk, division

I am working on generic code parser/highlighter and one user reported that he had problems with AWK code.

Basically, AWK defines '/' character as division operator and regex delimiter "/../". I would like to know how to distinguish between the two. When is '/' division operator and when does it represent start of regex?

Most web sites will just tell you "meaning of '/' depends on context", but I would like to know is there a simple rule that is used to distinguish the two meanings of forward slash.

I never worked with AWK, I know nothing of its internals, I am just looking for a way to parse AWK code. So, what would be the logic to parse '/' depending on context. If you wish you can write textual explanation or make a code (or pseudo code) demonstration. Though, I would prefer a simple C code without use of regex.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665213/differentiating-division-from-regex-when-lexing-gawk-code

Answer (score 3):

In general, the `//` literal regexp will never be immediately preceded by a literal or variable name. It may be preceeded by `~`, `!` and some other operators. In some cases `//` implicitly means `$0 ~ //`.

The `/` division operator will always be preceded by an rvalue (variable, function call, literal, expression), with `/=` as a special case.

Note that `awk` isn't as generous about whitespace as `C`,

```
printf("%i", 1
/2/3);
```

is not valid in awk. These however *are* valid(ish) awk (tested with `gawk` and `nawk`):

```
/a/+0/2 {print}     # regex /a/
b /a/+0/2 {print}   # not a regex (divide by zero)
## nawk will not accept anything after this line, gawk only
// {print}          # empty regex, awk is not C99
/**/ {print }       # dubious regex
/*/ { print "*/" }  # awk is not C
{print //}          # prints 1, equiv to ($0 ~ //)
/[/]/ { print }     # tricky regex
```

This is not a simple task to do robustly, if you're familiar with tokenizing and parsing, start here:

- http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/awkpretty/
- [Differentiating division from regex when lexing gawk code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665213/differentiating-division-from-regex-when-lexing-gawk-code)

The (ancient) `awkgram.y` (included with `awkpretty`) is a lot simpler reading than `gawk`'s.

You could probably do worse than parse the output of `awkpretty`:

```
$ awklex  '/a/+0/2 {print}'

# line 1 "/dev/stdin"
 47     token 47        /
335     REGEXPR a
 47     token 47        /
 43     token 43        +
333     NUMBER  0
 47     token 47        /
333     NUMBER  2
337     WHITESPACE       
123     token 123       {
319     PRINT   print
 59     token 59        }
125     token 125       }
  0     token 0
```

This will limit you to `nawk` compatible syntax though.

(If you need to compile `awkpretty` take care to use an old `bison`, `bison-1.35` works for me with "`YACC=bison-1.35 -y"` before `configure`.)

**Edit:** there seems to be a slight oddity in the output of `awklex`, token 59 is `;`, the final `token 59` may be an implied terminator but it's misrepresented with a `}`.
A note in `awkunlex.awk` implies it's a bug.

```
$ awklex  '/a/+0/2 {print}' | gawk -f awkunlex.awk 
/a/+0/2 {print}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed and useful post. I realize now that this is  non trivial task. Makes me wonder why AWK authors chose to make is so complex? Anyway, I discovered source code of one AWK parser on github, so I will have to check the source code directly in order to find out how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) says

```
In some contexts, a slash ( '/' ) that is used to surround an ERE could also
be the division operator. This shall be resolved in such a way that wherever
the division operator could appear, a slash is assumed to be the division
operator. (There is no unary division operator.)
```

See the "Grammar" section, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_16.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I find this paragraph really vague. "when it could appear", I would like to see a definition of some sort that defines when division could appear. For that I guess checking source code is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to work on "Is it a calculation". Get a yes/no from that, and act appropriately. Can a regular expression disguise itself as a valid piece of arithmetic? I could be wrong, but can't visualise it.

Comment: That is really complicated in a generic code parser. In a dedicated code parser you can just make another function and get a result from it, in a generic parser things become really complicated when you try to do so. But for AWK this seems to be the only way to go.